# Stored procedure list and parameter number used in conjunction with ComboBox

Tags: t-sql, c#-4.0, stored-procedures, combobox

I'm trying to get a list of all the user defined stored procedures to populate a combobox with. The idea was to manually create a table with the following columns:

> SProc Name, Number of Inputs, Parameter 1, Parameter 2 ...

The user is meant to click a button and a SProc selects all this data from that table, loads it into an array and populates the combo box.

The User is meant to then select a stored proc name from the combobox, and the number of parameters required are shown (with the relevant names).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per our discussion in SO chat:

```
SELECT
    sprocs.ROUTINE_NAME,
    parms.PARAMETER_NAME,
    parms.DATA_TYPE
FROM
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES sprocs
    LEFT OUTER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PARAMETERS parms ON parms.SPECIFIC_NAME = sprocs.ROUTINE_NAME
WHERE
    sprocs.ROUTINE_TYPE = 'PROCEDURE'
    --AND PATINDEX('/*<SomeKeyToSearch>*/', sprocs.ROUTINE_DEFINITION) > 0
```

This will give you the list of all sprocs with their parameters and data types. Just be warned that you also need to pay close attention to data types (precision, scale, max length, etc), since this will be used to allow a user to call an arbitrary stored procedure. Once you get this entire table in your C# application, you can group/sort/limit based on whatever criteria you want. If you want to ensure only specific sprocs get returned from the above query, just add a top-level comment to the sproc with some sort of key that you can search on.

Good luck.